# ListView inserted item's index

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, indexing

I have a ListView and sorting is enabled, once I insert an item, how do I get that item's index?

I can use the ListViewItem returned by the Add method of ListView, but is its index before sort or after? And is it updated if it is sorted again? Like if I store the ListViewItem and the ListView is then sorted, will the ListViewItem I stored earlier, its Index property would be updated too?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you add:

```
ListViewItem item = ...;
listView.Items.Add(item);
int index = item.Index;
```

or

```
ListViewItem item = listView.Items.Add("ItemName");
int index = item.Index;
```

To answer your questions that I missed before: yes, the indexes should be updated.

Comment: Can I get O(1)? What is ListViewItem.Name property? Can I use it as a key like in a dictionary?

Comment: @ListViewItem: It is an `O(1)` operation when using `listView.Items[5]`. You can use the `ListViewItem.Name` property as a key, but `listView.Items["name"]` is an `O(n)` operation and an `O(1)` operation **only when** the `<last accessed item>.Name == "name"`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are adding a `ListViewItem`:

```
listView.Items.Add(myItem);
int index = listView.Items.IndexOf(myItem);
```

Comment: Is it fast? What is its complexity? Is it instant?

Comment: @ListViewItem: It's not - O(n). Check my answer for a fast method.

Comment: Why do you care about speed? The item lookup will not be a problem. If you have enough items to have to care about speed you'll have to use virtual mode anyway. Don't do any premature optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `listView.Items.IndexOfKey(name_of_your_item_goes_here)` or `listView.Items.IndexOf(your_new_item)` if you care to create ListViewItems before adding them to list.